# Exporting Git repo from many timestamps to new timestamp dirs?

Tags: git

I cannot remember which commit was a certain stage: now I need to export all commits to different directories to test them. How can I export all repos with the different timestamps to new directories?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's too late to say: give your commits good comments! ;)

Comment: @GreenAsJade actually I am very sure that the right commit is `2014-01-16 02:59`, yet it would be nice to run the repo after each commit fast.

Comment: A good answer would depend on the specifics. Why do you need to export the commits into different directories? What type of test do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem by using a Git UI, rather than checking out every commit.

For example, using SourceTree you can click on each commit (it's a node in the graph) and see instantly the deltas to that node, and/or the state of the code at that node - without having to check the whole commit out.   I think this way you will quickly find the commit that you are looking for IF you know what you are looking for by source.

If you need to actually build and test each commit, this isn't a helpful suggestion for you (I will try to address that one separately).

Comment: I use tig for this but now I would like to run each commit without rereading everything again, for me the fastest is just to run a specific stage of the repo and see how it works, without reading everything. Basically I could also ask: is there some easy way to run a git repo with a certain timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet found a working solution but some suggestions from Freenode's Git below. Perhaps the easiest way is `git stash` and test the file after each command.

**[Git-bisect](http://jk.gs/git-bisect.html) for finding a bug in last ten commits (requires proper error-handling)**

```
$ git bisect start HEAD HEAD~10 --   # culprit is among the last 10
$ git bisect run ~/test.sh
$ git bisect reset                   # quit the bisect session
```

**Git log for getting commit hashes**

```
git log --pretty=format:%H  HEAD~10..HEAD | while read i; do git checkout $i; ./test.sh; done
```

**[Git Archive](http://jk.gs/git-archive.html) for exporting (manual work and not sure whether export everything)**